# Why exactly eight days of mourning for Prince Philip’s death?

Tags: united-kingdom

[Prince Philip, Duke of Edinburgh](http://Wikipedia%20entry) opted out for his state funeral.

Thus, an 8-day mourning period was issued instead in the United Kingdom.

I can’t figure out why that period was determined exactly in **eight** days (and not, say, seven as in a week, six as half a dozen, twelve, ten etc.).

I looked at [Wikipedia:ChristianBurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_burial), but unfortunately it shed no further light on the number of days that Christian tradition allows from death to burial. [NewAdvent.org](http://newadvent.org/cathen/03071a.htm) makes the case of “keeping the corpses of important persons for seven days” before performing the burial; it’s sorta clue, IMHO.

Comment: For many Christians, I believe this corresponds to the usual maximum number of days after death for a funeral to be held (seven, though it could be as few as two), plus one day for the funeral itself = eight. (Just a comment as I'm not sure if this is correct)

Comment: @LarsBosteen Thank you, your supposition is better than getting no answer at all. I will try and find something of the kind on my own.

Comment: Move all content into the question and flag comments for deletion. People are much less likely to bother with a question if they have to read the comment string to understand it.  Long comment strings are perceived as a symptom of a poor question.

Comment: Technically this is a question about the present/future.  Is there any evidence that historical sources and methods could help to answer this question?

Comment: Wiki page on [National Day of Mourning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_day_of_mourning) doesn't seem to indicate any standards, pattern or reasons. It looks to just be a recognition of status.

Comment: You have it backwards. The funeral occurs when it does, and official mourning [flags at half-mast etc] lasts until that day. And in fact that's the same whether there's a state funeral or not.

Comment: @justCal It varies per country. Thailand had one full year of official mourning for king Rama IX.

Comment: There's no standardised period: Diana, Princess of Wales died on Aug 31 and was buried on Sept 6; the Queen Mother died 30 March 2002 and was buried 9 April. I assume that as with any other death in the UK, a funeral is held whenever it's most convenient (based on time to organise, availability of venue and participants, etc).

Comment: See [octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_(liturgy)) and [afterfeast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afterfeast).